# Why do we need to normalize a WAV file before calculating the FFT?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, python

I am trying to calculate the FFT of a signal stored in a WAV file using SciPy. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377665/python-scipy-fft-wav-files), but it seems like we need to perform this step before the FFT:

```
b=[(ele/2**8.)*2-1 for ele in a] # this is 8-bit track, b is now normalized on [-1,1)
```

where the signal samples are stored in array `a`. Can someone explain the significance of this step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the WAV file used in that example has samples with values between 0 and 255 (likely stored as unsigned chars). The normalization step just changes the samples to floating point values in the range [-1,1). This is, strictly speaking, not necessary to perform the FFT, but it is a good idea. For instance, it removes the large DC component that results from interpreting the unsigned char values as actual signal amplitudes.

Comment: Yeah, WAV files are unsigned for 8 bit or less, and signed for 9 bit or higher. http://www.tactilemedia.com/info/MCI_Control_Info.html